# What is going on with my cactus. Someone said miners but idk

Tags: plant-health, diseases, leaves, plant-care

my night bLooming cactus has its leaves eaten like this. I don’t see a bug on it. Ive Sprayed it with water etc and researched online but just two people answered and they said miners. I don’t know if it’s actually miners. Any help
Appreciated please. [image]

Comment: You definitely have leaf miners!  Skeletonizers. You may have also had some nibbling by a rodent?  But leaf miners is what you've got. These guys are right.  Sorry?

Answer (score 3):

This damage is what's known as 'skeletonized' - it's usually caused by insect larvae that eat between the veins of a leaf, leaving behind this typical 'lacework' look to the leaves. Later, once it becomes an adult, it usually disappears altogether. This is not the same thing as leaf miners - those leave what looks like a trail inside the leaf tissue, rarely causing this skeletonized effect - the larvae which have done this could just as easily have been under or on top of the leaves. Quite which insect has caused the problem is hard to say - have a good look at the leaves, including the backs, as well as the stems with a magnifying glass to see if you can find any larvae or insects anywhere, but its possible they've all gone already. https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/insects/skeletonized-plant-leaves.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!